# how to include days of previous month in a calendar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have a calendar for day view, month view and week view. In month view all the days in the particular month (month which user selects) will be displayed in a grid. Suppose if a month begins by wednesday/thursday then the cells of monday, tuesday remains blank. Instead I need to display last two days of previous month and similarly if the month ends on monday/tuesday then the remaining cells should be filled with starting dates of succeeding month. pls provide code for this functionality..... thanx in advance...  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try using a premade control like the ASP .Net calendar control or jquery UI's DatePicker?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

I am not sure what your requirements are. Maybe there is a control out there that can work for you?

If you want to do this yourself, how are you programming it? Can you explain a little more of how you are creating this control?